# 3D Gaussian Filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, gaussian

Is there a 3D eqivalent of [imfilter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imfilter.html) available for MATLAB? I wish to apply Gaussian filtering to a 3D histogram. I was going to implement it myself, by creating a (3D) Gaussian filter, then looping over each element in my histogram, and summing up the corresponding data entries.

However, I didn't want to implement it myself in a slow and inefficient way if there's something already out there, or a cleverer way of doing it.

Comment: Assuming your Gaussian filter is separable then you should be able to apply a 2D filter followed by a 1D filter ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this in order to do the filtering in an efficient manner:

(1) Use [CONVN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convn.html) three times to filter your data with three 1D Gaussians, one x-by-1-by-1, one 1-by-y-by-1, and one 1-by-1-by-z.

(2) If you have the signal processing toolbox, use [FFTFILT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/fftfilt.html) to perform filtering in inverse space (or use any one of the fft-convolution algorithms on the file exchange).

[(3) Send me an email and I'll send you my `fftFilterImage`, which does 3D Gauss filtering.]

Answer (score 4):

imfilter can already do 3D filtering, as long as the data matrix and the filter you give it are 3D.  See [the imfilter page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imfilter.html).

Answer (score 2):

This task can be handled with the new (as of R2015a) [`imgaussfilt3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt3.html) function.

The basic syntax is as follows:

```
B = imgaussfilt3(A,sigma)
```

There are also a number of [name-value pair arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt3.html#namevaluepairs):

- `'FilterSize'`: Size of the Gaussian filter, defaulting to a cube of size `2*ceil(2*sigma)+1`.
- `'Padding'`: Type of padding (`'replicate'` (default) | `'circular'` | `'symmetric'`).
- `'FilterDomain'`: Perform convolution in domain: `'frequency'` or `'spatial'` (default auto).